# A really inefficient calculator

Tags: code-golf, restricted-complexity

Challenge: Add two numbers. In O(n^m) time, where n and m are the two numbers given. Sleeping, or your language equivalent, is not allowed.

Input: Two integers, separated by a space.

Output: The sum of the two integers.

Additional notes: The exact timing doesn't matter, as long as the input `1000 2` takes roughly 1/1000th the time as the input `1000 3`

Comment: O(n^m) time means at most n^m asymptotically. I think you want theta.

Comment: I presume you want people to use some kind of super slow algorithm, but there's nothing stopping them from doing simple addition followed by an `n^m` loop of NOPs to pad the runtime. I don't think there's a way around that (we do not allow unobservable requirements) but just a warning that submissions may be less interesting than you envisioned.

Comment: Is it OK if a program takes n^m time to complete after printing the sum, or would it have to take the time before printing?

Comment: Why the awkward input requirement. Can I really not just take two arguments?

Comment: So `2 100` should be approximately 100 septillion times slower than `100 2`?

Comment: Maybe try the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/32352) next time to get feedback on your challenge before you post it. And why not try to answer some challenges yourself! Then you get a good feel for what works.

Comment: @Sanchises Given that all of the current answers are doing effectively that (no-op to pad run time) I'll guess that they're allowed...

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit infix function:

```apl
⊃*⍴+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FXs9aj3i3a/9MetU141Nv3qG@qpz9Q8NB640dtE4G84CBnIBni4Rn8XzM5v6BSISUtr1ghObegggtEKKgbGhgopCkYqaNwjdUB)

However, if it really needs to take the two arguments together, separated by a space, we need the following anonymous tacit prefix function:

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 6 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
⊃*/⍴+/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FXs5b@o94t2vr/0x61TXjU2/eob6qnP1D40HrjR20TgbzgIGcgGeLhGfxfMzm/oFIhJS2vWCE5t6CCC0QoqKcpGBoYKBipo3CN1QE)

`+` or `+/` sum the numbers

`⍴` cyclically **r**eshape that to the following length:

`*` or `*/` one number raised to the power of the other

`⊃` pick the first element of that

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes

```python
lambda n,m:sum(range(n**m))and m+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ9equDRXoygxLz1VI09LK1dTMzEvRSFXO@9/QVFmXolGmoahgYGBjrGm5n8A)

Alternatively, as suggested by [user202729](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69850/user202729):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda n,m:n**m*[1]and n+m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ9cqT0srVyvaMDYxL0UhTzv3f0FRZl6JQpqGoYGBjpEmFzLXWPM/AA)

which also works with Python 3.

Comment: Why `sum(`…`)`? Isn't `range(n**m)` already \$O(n^m)\$?

Comment: @Adám Yes in Python 2, but not in Python 3 where `range` doesn't actually create the list: [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EoygxLz1Vw9BAS8vQwEBT8/9/AA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: What about `[1]*`?

Comment: @user202729 : I'd guess you're right.